# Connecting to Neo4j with Loopback connector neo4j, result gives HTTP endpoints

Tags: neo4j, loopback4

I have a backend created with Loopback4 , i installed the loopback-connector-neo4j connector, created a datasource.
In my code i run a cypher raw query.

As a result i obtain HTTP endpoints for Nodes and Relationships instaead of real data as is:

```
{
  path: {
    relationships: [ 'http://127.0.0.1:7575/db/data/relationship/2080' ],
    nodes: [
      'http://127.0.0.1:7575/db/data/node/212',
      'http://127.0.0.1:7575/db/data/node/5845'
    ],
    directions: [ '->' ],
    length: 1,
    start: 'http://127.0.0.1:7575/db/data/node/212',
    end: 'http://127.0.0.1:7575/db/data/node/5845'
  }
}
```

Perhaps it is due to the fact the loopback connector is connected to neo4j through Http and not bolt

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found a Neo4j bolt connector for loopback on Github that seems to solve the problem. Now i see the data content